# Showing a permutation module is reducible

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations, modules, representation-theory

[CROSS POST](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219998/showing-a-permutation-module-is-reducible)

For a permutation module $V$, which is a permutation module if it has the basis $B = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ such that the matrix of every $g \in G$ with respect to this basis is a permutation matrix. I need to show that a permutation module is always reducible.

I'm much more interested in how you approach solving this problem than what the answer is.

Is a permutation matrix a matrix which maps each basis vector to another basis vector, like a bijection? How would I better describe this property?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain what I said on MO (and also explaining what goes on in knsam's answer): The way to think about this is that since the group permutes the given basis vectors, it fixes the sum of all the given basis vectors. This gives a $1$-dimensional invariant submodule.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Arguably, the simplest invariant subspace would be one of dimension $1$. What would such a thing be? Do you see any such subspace in this case?

Comment: The <1..1> vector? Wouldnt that be trivial, and thus, not a proper submodule?

Comment: Hi! The $0$-module (sometimes also the full module itself) is what is usually called the trivial submodule. So, you have it right: what you have is a proper submodule provided $n > 1$ ($n$ as in your question).